# django import (different directories) - best practice

Tags: django, import, module

I have a Django project under `/var/www/django/my_proj` and I need to import python modules from `~/my_folder`.

What is the best practice of doing this?

Any way to do this through Django setting?

Comment: Have you created __init__.py files ?
You can just add ~/myfolder path to your python/django path.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you are deploying your site, ie., what server you are running, and you don't say anything about that.

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco - I added the __init__.py files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `~/my_folder` to `sys.path`.

This isn't necessarily the cleanest way to do it, but the quick way is probably to do that in your `settings.py` file. `settings.py` is a Python script just like anything else, so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/yourname/my_folder/')
```

Note that this is only an acceptable solution until you deploy; once you deploy, presumably your modules will be elsewhere, and you'll want to do your `sys.path` modification in your mod_wsgi conf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **virtualenvwrapper**, just use `add2virtualenv` to add the path to your `virtualenv_path_extensions.pth`:

http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv